# push remotes/origin/branch to the remote

Tags: git, github, git-push

So I created a branch on one machine "slide-security-fix" pushed it to the remote, then I switched to another machine, cloned created branch and made some changes, however this branch on my local machine is now called remotes/origin/slide-security-fix. So I am trying to push this branch back to remote with applied changes:

```
git push origin remotes/origin/slide-security-fix
```

but it gives me the error:

```
error: src refspec remotes/origin/slide-security-fix matches more than one.
error: failed to push some refs to 'myrepo.git'
```

I was looking for solution and the only thing I found was to specify my remote branch explicitly:

```
git push origin remotes/origin/slide-security-fix:remotes/origin/slide-security-fix
```

But it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be

```
git push origin HEAD:slide-security-fix
```

it will tell git to push the commit currently checked out, on the branch called `slide-security-fix` of the remote

You could also give a proper name to the branch you're working on. You could for example do

```
#Create a local branch on the current commit. Call it slide-security-fix. And check it out
git checkout -b slide-security-fix

#Then push
git push origin slide-security-fix
```

Answer (score 0):

`git push origin origin/slide-security-fix`